# How do you specify which django version to use? 

Tags: django

I am using ubuntu and I have installed django from the Ubuntu Software Center. For some projects I want to use the django cloned from the trunk instead of the default one. How can i do that ? Do I need to unistall the one provided by ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, simply make sure that the one you want to use shows up in an earlier directory in `sys.path`.

Comment: and how do i do that , the only way i know to modify sys.path is to change it at runtime.

Comment: Then do it at runtime, when needing the newer version of Django matters.

Comment: which file is needs to be changed in django?

Comment: None. Change the script that needs the special version of Django.

Answer (score 3):

Create a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for your django (with --no-site-packages) and activate it. Then install everything you need inside it.

Answer (score 0):

if wsgi in use 
then set the path to the desired django installation in the `django.wsgi` file. eg

```
import os
import sys
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
sys.path[:0] = ['/path/to/django/version/','/path/to/project/']
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

If modpython then set the path in the apache configuration file

```
PythonPath "['/path/to/django/version','/path/to/project'] + sys.path"
```

The docs might help:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/